# Collect links from a page using filters using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, href

I need to parse a list of YouTube video links using the query I need and the filter

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time 

name = 'hello world'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
id_serth = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "search_query")
id_serth.send_keys(name)
button_serth = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-icon-legacy")
time.sleep(1)
button_serth.click()
time.sleep(3)
button_filtr = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME ,"ytd-toggle-button-renderer")
button_filtr.click()
time.sleep(3)
button_filtrtode=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ytd-search-filter-renderer")
button_filtrtode.click()


#linkvideo2 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "video-title").get_attribute("href")
time.sleep(3)

urltek = driver.current_url

linkvideo2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="video-title"]').get_attribute('href')


print (linkvideo2)
print (urltek)
```

I get the answer None p.s just recently started learning selenium don't beat me)

```
None
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=hello+world&sp=EgIIAQ%253D%253D
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that YouTube uses the ID `video-title` for multiple elements.
Your current query is getting a `<yt-formatted-string>` element which doesn't have the attribute `href`.

Change

```
linkvideo2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="video-title"]').get_attribute('href')
```

to

```
linkvideo2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@id="video-title"]').get_attribute('href')
```

in order to get the `<a>` element. Then your code will print the link to the first found video.

If you want to print all found links, you could use something like that:

```
videos = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "ytd-video-renderer")
for video in videos:
    link = video.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a[@id="video-title"]')
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```